# Remove/Replace biblabel for a single bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am trying to insert my paper contributions into my PhD Thesis.
However, I want to add my contributions at the end of the first chapter, without interfering with the References in the last chapter.
As asked in the comments i provide a minimal working example, the code can be compiled with latexmk.
Latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,final,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese, english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=auto, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

% Chapter were my contributions should appear
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

\section{Introduction}
The work made by~\cite{Ceri:1982, Cattell:2011}.
Our work in~\cite{Antunes:2013, Antunes:2014:a}.

\section{Contributions}

In the following section we list the contributions made during this work.

\subsection{Conferences}
\defbibfilter{conferences}{keyword=phdcontribution and not type=article}
\printbibliography[heading=none,filter=conferences]
\subsection{Journals}
\defbibfilter{journals}{keyword=phdcontribution and type=article}
\printbibliography[heading=none,filter=journals]


% References of my thesis
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

%Redefine References name
\defbibheading{bibliography}[References]{
    \chapter{#1}
}
\SingleSpacing
\setlength\bibitemsep{8pt}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@InProceedings{Antunes:2013,
author    = {Mário Antunes and Diogo Gomes and Rui L. Aguiar},
title     = {Towards behaviour inference in smart environments},
booktitle = {2013 Conference on Future Internet Communications ({CFIC})},
year      = {2013},
publisher = {{IEEE}},
doi       = {10.1109/cfic.2013.6566324},
keywords  = {phdcontribution},
}

@InProceedings{Antunes:2014:a,
author    = {M. Antunes and D. Gomes and R. L. Aguiar},
title     = {Context storage for M2M scenarios},
booktitle = {2014 IEEE International Conference on Communications (ICC)},
year      = {2014},
pages     = {3664-3669},
doi       = {10.1109/ICC.2014.6883891},
keywords  = {phdcontribution},
}

@Article{Cattell:2011,
author  = {Cattell, Rick},
title   = {Scalable SQL and NoSQL Data Stores},
journal = {SIGMOD Rec.},
year    = {2011},
volume  = {39},
number  = {4},
pages   = {12-27},
issn    = {0163-5808},
doi     = {10.1145/1978915.1978919},
}

@InProceedings{Ceri:1982,
author    = {Ceri, S. and Negri, M. and Pelagatti, G.},
title     = {Horizontal data partitioning in database design},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1982 ACM SIGMOD international conference on Management of data},
year      = {1982},
pages     = {128-136},
doi       = {10.1145/582353.582376},
}
```

How can I replace the biblabel to have continuous numbering (not the numbering in the references chapter), and sort by date?

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). That way we can make sure that the solutions we come up with actually work for you. Could you describe in more detail what you need. Do you want to cite some of your own contributions? What style does the full bibliography have. What style should your list of contributions have?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: This is still not an MWE/MWEB we can work with (the two words are links in my first comment, please have a look at both links). I'm also still not sure if you want to `\cite` your own contributions and where they would appear if you `\cite` them. I would also need to know the style you currently have and the style you desire in more detail.

Comment: Any news here? Your question is a bit unclear without the additional requested details and MWE.

Comment: Finnish adding the minimal working example.

Comment: Mhhh, I still don't quite get what you want. You want to cite your own publications as well? And when you cite them explicitly, should they appear in the 'normal' references as well? Do you want your list of publications to be unnumbered as suggested in the title?

Comment: In section Contributions I want to filter out the reference list for my own works and print a small bibliography with my work. In this example is easy, only two are mine. In my thesis is way more than two. So i wanted a section with a small bibliography with just my own work, that i have done. What I do not known how to do is change the style of that small bibliography.

Comment: The question is what style do you want. You only say "How can I replace the biblabel to have continuous numbering (not the numbering in the references chapter), and sort by date?". But I'm not sure which bibliography this refers to and what you mean by "continuous numbering (not the numbering in the references chapter)". And if you go with a numbering, will it not confuse your readers to no end if one number is assigned to two different publications?

Comment: No, because in the text where the cite commands era used I want to appear the number of the publication in the References section. The contribution section is not a bibliography, I want to use the bibliography commands from latex to easy the process of adding all my papers, but in fact is a contribution section that lists the work I have done. Can i change the style only for this section?

Answer (score 1):

For a list of publications it makes sense to open a new `refsection` that `refsection` is independent of the rest of your document and citations. While it is in general not possible to change the citation or bibliography style mid-document (`biblatex` can only load one bibliography style and one citation style), there are certain ways to change the output to achieve a similar effect.

The main idea is to enclose your list of publications in a `refsection` of its own, in that refesction you can order a different sorting with `\newrefcontext`. We simply issue a `\nocite{*}` to obtain all entries and then filter the publications as in your MWE. The different style of the bibliography is achieved with a different bibliography environment (defined with `\defbibenvironment{contribbib}` and used with `env=contribbib`). If you want a normal numbered list instead you can just remove the option `env=contribbib` to `\printbibliography` and the definition of the `contribbib` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,final,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese, english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Antunes:2013,
author    = {Mário Antunes and Diogo Gomes and Rui L. Aguiar},
title     = {Towards behaviour inference in smart environments},
booktitle = {2013 Conference on Future Internet Communications ({CFIC})},
year      = {2013},
publisher = {{IEEE}},
doi       = {10.1109/cfic.2013.6566324},
keywords  = {phdcontribution},
}

@InProceedings{Antunes:2014:a,
author    = {M. Antunes and D. Gomes and R. L. Aguiar},
title     = {Context storage for M2M scenarios},
booktitle = {2014 IEEE International Conference on Communications (ICC)},
year      = {2014},
pages     = {3664-3669},
doi       = {10.1109/ICC.2014.6883891},
keywords  = {phdcontribution},
}

@article{Antunes:2014:b,
author    = {M. Antunes and D. Gomes and R. L. Aguiar},
title     = {Title},
journal   = {Journal of Stuff},
year      = {2014},
pages     = {345-365},
doi       = {10.1109/ICC.2014.6883891},
keywords  = {phdcontribution},
}

@Article{Cattell:2011,
author  = {Cattell, Rick},
title   = {Scalable SQL and NoSQL Data Stores},
journal = {SIGMOD Rec.},
year    = {2011},
volume  = {39},
number  = {4},
pages   = {12-27},
issn    = {0163-5808},
doi     = {10.1145/1978915.1978919},
}

@InProceedings{Ceri:1982,
author    = {Ceri, S. and Negri, M. and Pelagatti, G.},
title     = {Horizontal data partitioning in database design},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 1982 ACM SIGMOD international conference on Management of data},
year      = {1982},
pages     = {128-136},
doi       = {10.1145/582353.582376},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibheading{contribbib}{\subsection{#1}}
% to have an unnumbered list of contributions
\defbibenvironment{contribbib}
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang
     \itemindent-\leftmargin
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
     \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:introduction}

\section{Introduction}
The work made by~\cite{Ceri:1982, Cattell:2011}.
Our work in~\cite{Antunes:2013, Antunes:2014:a}.

\begin{refsection}
\newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]% or ydnt for descending order
\section{Contributions}
In the following section we list the contributions made during this work.
\nocite{*}% or explicitly: \nocite{Antunes:2013,Antunes:2014:a,...}

\defbibfilter{conferences}{keyword=phdcontribution and not type=article}
\printbibliography[env=contribbib, heading=contribbib, title=Conferences, filter=conferences]
\defbibfilter{journals}{keyword=phdcontribution and type=article}
\printbibliography[env=contribbib, heading=contribbib, title=Journals, filter=journals]
\end{refsection}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\SingleSpacing
\setlength\bibitemsep{8pt}
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title=\refname]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the introduction chapter with two unnumbered lists of publications.]

[image: Screenshot of the references section in chapter 2]